# customizing an info window with geolocation views

Tags: views, theming

I have been beating myself up a lot with this problem.  I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am using Drupal 7, using the geolocation module, specifically the views part.

I am essentially trying to put a view for each node within this map view.

It works really well, however, it doesn't render in a particularly nice way for the user.

[image]

I am guessing that I can sort this out in css.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out which div class to alter.  The one that I think I want to alter is just a standard Div tag.  I am sure I am missing something, but I just can't work it out.  I tried altering the .balloon class, but got some weird results.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Mark.

Comment: Where is the css being pulled from? Are there module specific tpl files? I assume you mean IP geolocation and views module.

Comment: Yes I am using the IP Geolocation module, specifically the views part of it.

Comment: Right, well the module probably has a tpl file or at least loads some CSS to control the display. Once you figure out where that is you can override the styles or write your own. Poke around in the module file or check the views advanced settings, you can maybe add a CSS class to your views there style the new class

Comment: Yes your right about the CSS.  Found 2 files.  Couldn't find any .tpl files, but found a few .js files.  Trying to work it out, but I am being dumb.  I figure my best solution is to try and override the overflow option from hidden / auto to visible.  Thanks for the help so far though...

Comment: Can you update your post with the CSS you want to change and what you want it to look like? You can try the devel theme module to get more info about what your site is doing to display the page. Again, you should be able to assign your views a CSS class for more granular control

Comment: Ok I will have a look at that.  Actually ran into a bit of a problem.  I was looking at using the leaflet version of the map instead.  However after installing leaflet, geofield and geophp (and leaflet views).  I found that other than the root user, nobody could view a googlemap.  Currently trying to revert the changes, but well, it seems to effect the file system rather than the database...hopefully should be getting back on track...

Comment: I am back up and running.  So when I use firebug or the web developer tools in firefox I find that the main tag I want to alter is contained in a normal <div> tag with no class style so nothing I can alter.  The content is actually then rendered into another <div> tag: <div clas="gm-style-iw"  I have managed to alter this in CSS, but it doesn't actually eleminate the scroll bars along the bottom.  Reading the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015834/how-to-remove-scrollbars-from-google-map-bubble-in-google-map-javascript-v3 I think I need to alter the max-width setting.

Comment: But I think I need to do this in the div tag which seems to be controlled inline?  Via the module I think?  Really finding it very difficult to work out exactly what I need to alter.  If you look at the bottom photo I upload this should show what I am going about

Comment: might have resolved this issue by altering the maxWidth setting for the infoWindow in a .js file.  But I figure its worth checking with the developer to see if this could be a fix?!

Answer (score 1):

Having clarified this with the developer, you need to alter the  ip_geoloc_gmap_multi_loc.js file at line
165.  This relates to the infoWindow maxWidth setting.  Essentially I have
tried to increase this massively.

This sorts out the problem for me, and the developer advised me that this should not cause a problem.

I couldn't work out how to do this with css.  Might be possible...but I couldn't work it out...

...hope this helps someone in the future, as it caused me quite a headache!

Thanks again for your posts,

Mark.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I was out of commission for a few days. Glad you worked it out.

Comment: No worries.  Hope that this might be of use if anyone else hits the issue...thanks for the help though ;)